# WinRT bing maps not working

Tags: windows-runtime, bing-maps

I downloaded bing maps for windows rt 8.1. I created a new project in visual studio and I added the bing maps reference. But every time I try to add a map I get an error that says A reference to bing maps has been added.

And each time I try to add the map in the designer I get an error: a reference to bing maps has been added. But this shouldn't happen because I already added the references.

Comment: But, what's the actual problem you're having? The error doesn't provide anything useful .. is the map itself not working?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set the active solution platform of your application. Go to Build -> Configuration Manager and change the platform to x86. Because Bing Maps makes use of the C++ Runtime you have to specify the target platform. This is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456475.aspx